# Altering bools that are part of a list

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm quite new to C#, and have been trying my hand at creating a simple level-to-level game with a save system with which I was going to use a global bool array in order to keep progress of level progression, but after finding that doing a List would be better, I decided instead to use that.
However, I can't seem to find a way to alter bool values in the list. Could I have some assistance?

This is the C# that I'm using for the list. As you can see, I've made a separate class to hold it. Not sure if that's causing any issues.

```
namespace Project
{
    public static class Nights
    {
        public static List<bool> nights = new List<bool>(5) { true };
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried in order to _alter_ values in that list and what error did you get?

Comment: You may also be interested in a [BitArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=net-8.0) ?

Comment: You can index list items just as with arrays: `nights[i] = true;`. Note that your code adds 1 element to the list. You must add elements to the list. 5 in your example is just the initial size of the inner array. It is not the number of elements the list contains. `nights.Add(true); nights.Add(false);` etc. then you can index them.

Comment: You should probably try to avoid using "static" for anything that can change. Global mutable state has been considered harmful for many years now. You might also reconsider if a list of bools is really the best type of data storage. What will happen if you add or remove a level? A list of level identifiers for cleared levels might be better, or create a serializable class that can contain your entire game-state.

Answer (score -1):

We need to look at this expression:

```
new List<bool>(5) { true }
```

The `5` here doesn't mean what you think it does. It creates a new list with an **initial buffer** capacity of 5. However, only **one** entry (`true`) is added to this list and initial `Length` is still just **1**. You are not yet able to access later items from the initial buffer by index.

So at this point, you could write `nights[0] = false;` and change that item, but `nights[1]` and later *do not exist yet*. If you want there to be 5 items, you still need to `.Add()` four more entries.

Additionally, the `5` is only an *initial* capacity. You can keep adding more and more items to the list beyond this. The 5 is only used for the initial buffer allocation, but the list is still able to grow from there.

What you probably wanted was this:

```
 new List<bool>(5) { true, true, true, true, true }
```

Now you can use nights[1], nights[2], etc to change those items.

Answer (score -2):

This should work, assuming night is 0-based and there are 5 levels.

```
namespace Project
{
    public static class Nights
    {
        private static int MAX_NIGHTS = 5;
        public static List<bool> nights = new List<bool>(MAX_NIGHTS);

        // Initialize the nights array to all false
        static Nights() 
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < MAX_NIGHTS; n++)
                nights.Add(false);
        }

        // If we make it to Night #night, set all nights up to this one true
        public static void SaveLevelProgress(int night)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < night; n++)
                nights[n] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That `List<T>` constructor merely reserves memory, so that assignment will throw an exception.